# How do I sys_write multiple ASCII characters on x64?

Tags: assembly, x86-64, nasm

I am learning assembly and a number of guides explain how to `sys_write` but only using data stored in `.text`. I want to print multiple ASCII characters stored on the stack.

```
global _start

section .data

section .text

_start:
    push rbp
    mov rbp, rsp

    sub rsp, 16
    mov QWORD [rbp], 47
    mov QWORD [rbp - 8], 46
    
    mov rax, 1
    mov rdi, 1
    lea rsi, [rbp]
    mov rdx, 2
    syscall

    pop rbp
    
    mov rax, 60
    mov rdi, 0
    syscall
```

The above code sets up the stack frame (useless for the example), makes room for the local variables and places the ASCII characters for 47 and 46 on the stack. Then it loads the address to the first ASCII character into `rsi` and calls `sys_write`. Finally, it calls `sys_exit`.

However, when I run the code it only prints: `/^@`. Running strace produces the following output:

```
execve("./a.out", ["./a.out"], 0x7ffd1d1c2280 /* 60 vars */) = 0
write(1, "/\0", 2/\0)                      = 2
exit(0)                                 = ?
+++ exited with 0 +++
```

I feel like there's a fundamental misunderstanding I have concerning `lea` or `[rbp]` but I don't know enough assembly to know what I am missing.

Comment: Is it that you're moving QWORDs instead of bytes?

Comment: Draw yourself a picture of the stack.  You want the two bytes 46 and 47 at consecutive addresses, and the `syscall` expects a pointer to the first of the two (the lower address).  You have instead put them 8 bytes apart, passed a pointer to the second one, and to top it off moving into `[rbp]` overwrites the saved frame pointer.

Comment: And `pop rbp` makes no sense until you have moved the stack pointer back to where `rbp` was stored (you subtracted 16 but never added back).  On the other hand, since you are calling the `exit` system call, you never return to the caller anyway, so why bother to save its registers?

Comment: Thanks very much @NateEldredge and @possum!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming this is on linux or something linux-like, but your `read` is expecting a set of byte-packed chars, so the following change (keeping your 16 byte aligned stack)

```
    sub rsp, 16
    mov BYTE [rbp], 47
    mov BYTE [rbp-1], 46
    
    mov rax, 1
    mov rdi, 1
    lea rsi, [rbp-1]
    mov rdx, 2
    syscall
```

prints

```
./
```

Comment: Thanks, between this and the comments everything makes more sense!

Comment: I think you want `[rbp-1]` and `[rbp-2]`, else you are overwriting the low byte of the saved frame pointer.  Or better, use `[rsp]` and `[rsp+1]` and then there is no need to use the frame pointer at all.

Comment: This is true and rsp would be more canonical

Comment: Or more normally, `mov word [rbp-2], './'` or even just `push "./"` / `mov rsi, rsp`.  NASM allows multi-character literals to work as integer constants without messing them up (reversing them) the way some assemblers do (*cough* MASM).  Note that `syscall` doesn't care *at all* about the alignment of user-space RSP, or even if it's pointing to valid memory.  System calls don't use the user-space stack so you could even just `mov`-store to the red zone below RSP.